# Salesforce Case Url

Tags: case

I'm using case url like 'https://xxxx.salesforce.com/console#{{caseID}}. It did work well before, but it doesn't navigate the right case anymore and show 'Record deleted' message(It is not deleted!). Also, I checked permission, but even if I logged in System Administrator, it shows the 'Record deleted' message. I could find the case in case list manually, but still doesn't work the url.

Do you know any ideas to improve it?

Comment: Did your instance change? I.E. moving from na7 to na14? Also, if you go to a case that is not deleted and grab the url is it different than what you're working with now?

Answer (score 0):

I would go to the Case that you know exists, and then compare it to what your URL in question is.

It could be different domain, different instance, lightning url... lots of possibilities...